# How to create a DocumentTerm matrix from a corpus, having issues?

Tags: r, tm

file.txt has 58 rows and looks like

Row 1:48~91<4n>XXY,+X,-4,+der(6)t(1;6)(q21;q13),del(9)(q22),add(12)(p11.2)
Row 2:48,XY,t(1;9)(p34;p22),trp(1)(q32q42),add(4)(q35),+8

```
mydata<-read.table(file="file.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\t")
newdata <-strsplit(as.character(mydata$V1), split = ",") #splitting terms 
(,)
Corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(newdata))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus)
```

corpus produces (for example) \"-X\",\"-4\", \"+der(6)t(1;6)(q21;q13)\",ETC...
dtm produces just "der" in the above example.

Comment: This isn't related to your punctuation problem, but there is a difference between a `DocumentTermMatrix` and a `TermDocumentMatrix` - your text says one and your code says another, so make sure you are getting what you want. (The first word defines rows, the second defines columns.)

Comment: I think you'll get a better response if you create a reproducible example. Something like `Corpus = SimpleCorpus(x = VectorSource(c("hi.", "hello longword (hi)", "hello!")))`,  maybe a little more (or maybe not), and show that the resulting DTM (or TDM) eliminates short words and punctuation even when you tell it not to.

Comment: So,del(6)(p21p25)

Comment: the text follows like: del(6)(p21),+16,+8,-9...etc....  -this text is separated by the (,) . For example, a<-strsplit(as.character(mydata$V1), split = ",").  This is then placed in mycorpus: Corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(a)).  When I take a look at mycorpus, it is nicely separated:  \"del(6)(p21)\", \"+16\", \"+8"\, "\-9\".However,   dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus) drops everything and only produces "del" from this example.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the reproducible example, it is difficult to read and follow in the comments.

Comment: file has 58 rows (example row 1: del(6)(p21),+16,+8,-9...etc)........>mydata<-read.table(file="file.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\t")>..........newdata <-strsplit(as.character(mydata$V1), split = ",") .........<Corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(newdata)).......... <dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus) ........

Comment: *Please **edit your question** to include the reproducible example, it is difficult to read and follow in the comments.* You can find the `edit` button at the bottom of the question, just below the `r` and `tm` tags, next to "share". And please make the example **reproducible**, my earlier comment gave a nice example of code that anyone can copy/paste/run. We don't have your `file.txt`, so we can't copy/paste/run the ode you posted. It doesn't need to be long - just a few lines, entered as text, as in my comment above.